# Compare two columns of a csv file and show unmatched records only

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

I have a csv file in below format

```
1311,0008,a131,a131,7039
1311,0008,a131,a132,7039
1711,2046,a626565,a626566,7099
1711,2048,a626565,a626565,7035
```

What I want is to compare column 3 and 4 only and if they do not match, print that line in a new file and if they match print that line in another file

Expected File1 output (where col 3 & 4 do not match) :

```
1311,0008,a131,a132,7039
1711,2046,a626565,a626566,7099
```

Expected output in File2 (where col 3 & 4 match) :

```
1311,0008,a131,a131,7039
1711,2048,a626565,a626565,7035
```

So far I have tried the comparison with multiple files only.

Comment: Although you have an answer already, can you add the code that you tried to the question? Did it work? What do you mean by "with multiple files only"? I don't see that the question asks for a single file.

Comment: What i meant was so far i have used the comparison on multiple files only( like compare col2 of file1 with col2 of file2).. I didn't knew how to compare columns of a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two really short commands, just to keep it simple:

```bsh
awk -F, '$3 != $4' file.csv >file1
```

```bsh
awk -F, '$3 == $4' file.csv >file2
```

Both of these two commands treat the lines in `file.csv` as a set of comma-delimited fields.  Whenever the the third field is not equal to the fourth field, the first command writes the current line (and it is written to `file1` via an output redirection).  The second command does the same but with the opposite logic (and the output goes to `file2`).

Using a single command is slightly more complex, but allows you to name the output files on the command line with simple redirections from file descriptors 3 and 4:

```
$ awk -F, '{ fd = $3 == $4 ? 4 : 3;  print >("/dev/fd/" fd) }' file.csv 3>file1 4>file2
$ cat file1
1311,0008,a131,a132,7039
1711,2046,a626565,a626566,7099
$ cat file2
1311,0008,a131,a131,7039
1711,2048,a626565,a626565,7035
```

Or the same thing, but more obfuscated,

```bsh
awk -F, '{ print >("/dev/fd/" 3 + ($3 == $4)) }' file.csv 3>file1 4>file2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{ print >($3==$4?"matchedFile":"notMatchedFile") }' infile
```

that's selectively redirecting lines to one of the two output files, if column#3 was equally [full string match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/4023950) with column#4 (columns are delimited by comma character, it's specified by `-F,`), write to *`matchedFile`* output file, else writes to *`notMatchedFile`*.

see [other matching options here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/4023950).

---

```
$ head matchedFile notMatchedFile
==> matchedFile <==
1311,0008,a131,a131,7039
1711,2048,a626565,a626565,7035

==> notMatchedFile <==
1311,0008,a131,a132,7039
1711,2046,a626565,a626566,7099
```

---

or similarly but make command more compact:

```
awk -F, '{ print >"file"($3==$4) }' infile
```

---

```
$ head file[01]
==> file0 <==
1311,0008,a131,a132,7039
1711,2046,a626565,a626566,7099

==> file1 <==
1311,0008,a131,a131,7039
1711,2048,a626565,a626565,7035
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed method:

```
F="[^,]*,"
sed -En "
  /^($F){2}($F)\\2/w match.csv"'
  //!w nomatch.csv
' file.csv
```

Result are stored in match/nomatch .CSV files in the current directory.