# How to remove bad data after filtering it out to new file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Here is the example data I already sorted (3 columns):

CustomerId, fname, lname, email, gender, amount spent, creditcard, transaction-id, transactiondate, street, city, state, zip, phone

```
<redacted>
```

by using the command:

```
awk -F ',' '{ state = $12 ? $12: "exceptions.csv"; print}' < "03_conv_gender.tmp" > "04_filter_bad_data.tmp"
```

I check each row if they are missing a {state} value and if so it gets put in a new file called "exceptions.csv".

How would I delete the original bad data from the "04_filter_bad_data.tmp" or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The data can be one of two states, "good" or "bad", correct? Pseudo-code would be "if (GOOD) then (OUPUT to GOOD.TXT) else (OUTPUT to BAD.TXT) endif". This is basic construct/algorithm in any computer science course, and has countless examples on the web. Please do your research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two columns of a csv file and show unmatched records only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646614/compare-two-columns-of-a-csv-file-and-show-unmatched-records-only)

Comment: We have redacted your example data as it looked like it contained personal information. Please update your question with fake data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ print >($12==""?"badData.csv":"goodData.csv") }' infile
```

this splits input file to two separate output files, those line that having empty column#12 (*STATE* field) will be written into the file *"badData.csv"* otherwise it will be written into the *"goodData.csv"* output file.

Comment: This worked, but I was wondering how it works exactly because I want to learn. lets see if I got this right " I'm printing out everyting comparing at {STATE} -> if its blank? its baddata.csv or if its gooddata.csv read in from file?

Comment: @puuyo just added a short explain